# Web Forms - Login page not working (not redirecting) on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, webforms

I have created application using Web forms and all the functions are working fine while running on "localhost". Now i have put my app on iis and here comes the problem,

1. application is running and login page is opened,
2. after entering correct username and password - it redirects to the login page itself instead of redirecting to User dashboard.

*No error has been thrown, no logs recorded, even checked with windows event viewer.*

If i enter wrong credentials, no error message has been thrown(which is working on localhost)

i don't know what i am missing, please help me out.

Comment: You need to redirect to another page is username and password is correct

Comment: yes, as i said username and password are correct.

Comment: Are you redirecting?

Comment: not to the page specified, but to the login page itself.

Comment: Pleaes give the code where you written the code to go to dashboard after checking credential.Or give the code of whole login block. Otherwise it's not understandable.

Comment: @RajobRaihanMonmoy below is the code of login method

Answer (score 0):

Here is the login method

```
try
        {
            string username= txtusrid.Text.ToLower().Trim();
            string usrpwd= txtpwd.Text.Trim();

            cn= new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cntx"].ConnectionString);
            cn.Open();
            sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("_pdblogin", cn);
            sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Employee_Id", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 2500));
            sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pwd", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 2500));
            sqlcmd.Parameters["@Employee_Id"].Value = username;
            sqlcmd.Parameters["@pwd"].Value = usrpwd;
            reader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    usrfname = reader.GetValue(4).ToString();
                    Session["User"] = reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
            if (usrfname != "")
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]))
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, remcbx.Checked);
                    Response.Redirect(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]);
                }
                else
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username, remcbx.Checked);
                    Response.Redirect("/Userdashboard");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                dvMessage.Visible = true;
                errmsg.Text = "Username and/or password is incorrect.";
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            cn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: won't it be like ./Userdashboard ? (if it is in the same directory as the login page)

Comment: It's not working, yes, login and userdashboard pages are in same directory.

The function is working fine in localhost, am i really missing something here?